# How to cast a list of values within xquery in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xquery

I have the following T-SQL code that I am trying to get to work:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.xml_schema_collections WHERE name = 'TST') DROP XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TST; 
GO
CREATE XML SCHEMA COLLECTION TST AS N'<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><xsd:element name="root"><xsd:complexType><xsd:complexContent><xsd:restriction base="xsd:anyType"><xsd:sequence><xsd:element name="val" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xsd:string" /></xsd:sequence></xsd:restriction></xsd:complexContent></xsd:complexType></xsd:element></xsd:schema>';
GO
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';

SELECT @xml.value('sum(//val)','INT')
```

The `xsd` tells us that the `val` node is of type `string`. Therefor the `sum()` function won't work:

```
Msg 9308, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
XQuery [value()]: The argument of 'sum()' must be of a single numeric primitive type or 'http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-datatypes#untypedAtomic'. Found argument of type 'xs:string *'.
```

I have tried the following ways to get this to work:

---

**Option 1**:

One work-around is to just get rid of the xsd schema:

```
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';
SELECT (CAST(@xml AS XML)).value('sum(//val)','INT')
```

That returns the correct result: 6. However, it seems rather crude and might not always be an option (e.g. when dealing with XML indexes).

---

**(Non-)Option 2**:

An alternative is, to cast each value to `xs:integer` before summing them together. However, that is where I am stuck.

It is easy to cast a single element:

```
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';
SELECT @xml.value('sum(xs:integer((//val)[1]))','INT')
```

But that results in 1, which is the wrong result. This is expected, as now (because of the `[1]`) only the first `val` node gets looked at.

---

**(Non-)Option 3**:

There are two ways to write a cast in xquery:

```
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';
SELECT @xml.value('sum(xs:integer((//val)))','INT')
GO
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';
SELECT @xml.value('sum(((//val) cast as xs:integer ?))','INT')
```

However, both work only with singletons as input:

```
Msg 2365, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
XQuery [value()]: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xs:string *' to 'xs:integer'
Msg 2365, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
XQuery [value()]: Cannot explicitly convert from 'xs:string *' to 'xs:integer ?'
```

---

**(Non-)Option 4**:

According to the [xquery documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#id-map-operator) you should be able to do this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';
SELECT @xml.value('sum((//val)! xs:integer(.))','INT')
```

However, that is seems to not be implemented by SQL Server:

```
Msg 2217, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
XQuery [value()]: ',' or ')' expected
```

---

**Option 5**:

You could use the `.nodes()` function and solve the problem outside of xquery:

```
DECLARE @xml XML(TST) = '<root><val>1</val><val>2</val><val>3</val></root>';
SELECT SUM(X.V.value('.','INT')) FROM @xml.nodes('//val') X(V)
```

This results in the correct value of 6. However, I am looking for a solution within xquery, so this is not an option for me.

---

**Option ?**:

With that I am out of ideas. Is there a solution to this problem?

---

---

**Extra**:

In addition, I would really like to know what the `?` stands for in this line, taken from one of the examples above:

```
SELECT @xml.value('sum(((//val)[1] cast as xs:integer ?))','INT')
```

SQL Server requires it. You get this error, if you try without:

```
Msg 9301, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
XQuery [value()]: In this version of the server, 'cast as <type>' is not available. Please use the 'cast as <type> ?' syntax.
```

This error hints at the fact, that this requirement is a limitation of SQL Server. However, I was not able to find documentation about its meaning anywhere.

Comment: Is there a reason that you cannot change the schema to be an integer instead of a string? The question mark btw means that the sequence may be empty: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-30/ section 1.4

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone, thanks for the `?`. That makes a lot of sense. See also: https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#prod-xpath30-OccurrenceIndicator

Comment: @Mr.Brownstone, in the current setting I do not have control over the schema. So, I cannot change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it in xQuery with a [FLWOR Statement and Iteration (XQuery)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190945.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) using cast on each value returned.

```sql
SELECT @xml.value('sum(for $val in //val return $val cast as xs:int?)','INT')
```

A query like that could make you think that SQL Server will do some time consuming looping operations but if you have a look at the query plan you will see that is not the case. The for loop is transformed to a plan that gets all the values from a single call to a Table-valued function, converts them to an integer and then using an aggregate operator to calculate the sum.

[image]